# Why dataSkewness gives issues in spark?

Tags: java, apache-spark, dataset

I'm trying to understand issue which occurs while data skew in spark.

Lets say I 've below data and I `left outer join` with very small data set.

```
true //50 million records
false //50k records
```

So In above case, `true` records will be loaded in one partition, if that's overloaded, it should create other to sit into.

But where it gets stuck ? I'm trying to visualize it.

Please help me to understand this what happens in flow where it gets stuck. Read alot online, but not able to get it completely.

Comment: I think you should tell us a little more. Show a sample of the left and right datasets and the code if you do something special.

Answer (score 0):

Data skewness is when there are many small partitions and a small number of larger partitions of an rdd or dataframe that need to be processed. The few larger partitions will take longer to process than the smaller partitions. So you are wasting executors that were used for the smaller partitions if not returning them to the resource manager and the lack of even distribution which elongates the overall Stage time.

In your example you may think you have skewed data but likely are alluding to a JOIN of a large table with a small table. A so-called Broadcast JOIN, that is another matter well described everywhere these days. No issue this type of query, btw. Skewed data pertains to a single dataframe or rdd.